# Can someone pls tell me why my chain1 suddenly prints 99 the second time i use it ? :)

Tags: c

Can someone please tell me why chain1 is printing 99?

All I wanna do is swap the chain1 with the chain3 after the if conditions are completed, but chain1 suddenly jumps to 99 and I don't really know why. I even changed my other strings and it works out pretty well. 
For this condition, you type `a3` and then `c3` to swap chain1 with chain3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define R 3
#define C 3
#include <time.h>
#define S 100

int main()
{
    char CHAINASK[S];

    int index = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int Z = 0;

    char CHAIN1[S];
    char CHAIN2[S];
    char CHAIN3[S];
    char CHAIN4[S];
    char CHAIN5[S];
    char CHAIN6[S];
    char CHAIN7[S];
    char CHAIN8[S];
    char CHAIN9[S];

    int a, b;

    int c, n;

    ///random maker
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (c = 1; c <= 1; c++)
    {
        n = rand() % 4 + 1;
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    CHAIN1[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    CHAIN2[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    CHAIN3[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    CHAIN4[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    CHAIN5[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    CHAIN6[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    CHAIN7[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    CHAIN8[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
    CHAIN9[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;

    int q[R][C] = {CHAIN1[S], CHAIN2[S], CHAIN3[S], CHAIN4[S], CHAIN5[S], CHAIN6[S], CHAIN7[S], CHAIN8[S], CHAIN9[S]};

    for (a = 0; a < R; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < C; b++)
        {
        }
    }

    // PRINTS THE TABLE
    for (a = 0; a < R; a++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (b = 0; b < C; b++)
        {
            printf("%d,", q[a][b]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

////////////////////////////////
// the comparer
////////////////////////////////

    printf("Escriba su coordenada\n");
    scanf("%s", CHAINASK);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    if (strcmp(CHAINASK, "a3") == 0)
    {
        printf("eligio la casilla a3");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Escriba su coordenada\n");
        scanf("%s", CHAINASK);
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        if (strcmp(CHAINASK, "c3") == 0)
        {
            printf("eligio la casilla c3");
            printf("\n");
            printf("\n");

            // THE SWAP OCCURS

            int q[R][C] = {CHAIN1[S], CHAIN2[S], CHAIN3[S], CHAIN4[S], CHAIN5[S], CHAIN6[S], CHAIN9[S] CHAIN7[S], CHAIN8[S], };

            for (a = 0; a < R; a++)
            {
                for (b = 0; b < C; b++)
                {
                }
            }
            // PRINTS THE TABLE
            for (a = 0; a < R; a++)
            {
                printf("\n");
                for (b = 0; b < C; b++)
                {
                    printf("%d,", q[a][b]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(CHAINASK, "b3") == 0)
    {
        printf("eligio la casilla b3");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no valid coordinate was introduced");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two places where you seem to have empty inner loop bodies.  Those make the inner loop irrelevant, which in turn makes the outer loop irrelevant.  So, what were you planning to put in those empty inner loops?

Comment: i'm not able to replicate/generate the issue you are talking about. I ran the code and entered 'a3' and 'c3' but i'm not getting '99' anywhere. What do you mean by 'chain1 suddenly jumps to 99'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing **CHAINx** in the possition **S=100** or **CHAIN1[100]**, 
Your declaration of **CHAINx** is **char CHAIN1[S]** or **CHAIN1[100]**, this means that your index shall not be higher that 99  when reading or writing to CHAINx , e.g CHAIN[99]

one fix would be declaring your **CHAIN** as char **CHAIN[S+1]** , here the fixed code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


#define R 3
#define C 3
#define S 100
int main()
{
char CHAINASK[S+1];

int index = 0;
int z = 0;
int Z = 0;

char CHAIN1[S+1];
char CHAIN2[S+1];
char CHAIN3[S+1];
char CHAIN4[S+1];
char CHAIN5[S+1];
char CHAIN6[S+1];
char CHAIN7[S+1];
char CHAIN8[S+1];
char CHAIN9[S+1];

int a, b;

int c, n;

///random maker
srand(time(NULL));
for (c = 1; c <= 1; c++)
{
    n = rand() % 4 + 1;
    printf("%d\n", n);
}

printf("\n");
printf("\n");
CHAIN1[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
CHAIN2[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
CHAIN3[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
CHAIN4[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
CHAIN5[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
CHAIN6[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
CHAIN7[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
CHAIN8[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;
CHAIN9[S] = rand() % 4 + 1;

int q[R][C] = {CHAIN1[S], CHAIN2[S], CHAIN3[S], CHAIN4[S], CHAIN5[S], CHAIN6[S], CHAIN7[S], CHAIN8[S], CHAIN9[S]};

for (a = 0; a < R; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < C; b++)
    {
    }
}

// PRINTS THE TABLE
for (a = 0; a < R; a++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (b = 0; b < C; b++)
    {
        printf(" %d[%d,%d] , ", q[a][b],a,b);
    }
}
printf("\n");
printf("\n");

// the comparer


printf("Escriba su coordenada\n");
scanf("%s", CHAINASK);
printf("\n");
printf("\n");

if (strcmp(CHAINASK, "a3") == 0)
{
    printf("eligio la casilla a3");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Escriba su coordenada\n");
    scanf("%s", CHAINASK);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    if (strcmp(CHAINASK, "c3") == 0)
    {
        printf("eligio la casilla c3");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");

        // THE SWAP OCCURS

        int qd[R][C] = {CHAIN1[S], CHAIN2[S], CHAIN3[S],  CHAIN4[S], CHAIN5[S], CHAIN6[S],CHAIN9[S], CHAIN7[S], CHAIN8[S], };

        for (a = 0; a < R; a++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b < C; b++)
            {
            }
        }
        // PRINTS THE TABLE
        for (a = 0; a < R; a++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (b = 0; b < C; b++)
            {
                printf(" %d [%d,%d] , ", qd[a][b],a,b);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (strcmp(CHAINASK, "b3") == 0)
{
    printf("eligio la casilla b3");
}
else
{
    printf("no valid coordinate was introduced");
}
}
```

Comment: it works like i wanted :D thank you so much i was stuck on that for a while now XD

Comment: This looks OK but I wonder if OP still has some misconception. It's not clear why he declares arrays of 101 chars and then only ever uses the last index.

Comment: Indeed , there are a lot unclear parts, like the empty nested for loops.